# How to read both last and first names in text file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a very novice in C++. Just trying to learn one month ago. I am trying to figure out this problem:

A teacher has asked all her students to line up single file according to their last name.

Write a program that will read in a file of names. Names should be read until there are no more names to be read. The file I have has both last name and first name. I would like to display both names.

This is what I have so far, but it sorts by first name and just displays first name. How can I get it to sort by last name and display both last and first name?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;

    string lastname, firstname, 
        first,
        last;

    inputFile.open("RandomNames.txt");

    if (inputFile)
    {
    
        inputFile >> lastname;
        first = last = lastname;

        while (inputFile >> lastname)
        {
            if (lastname < first)
                first = lastname;

            else if (lastname > last)
                last = lastname;
        }

   
        inputFile.close();
    }

    cout << "First student in line = "
        << first;

    cout << "Last student in line  = "
        << last;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"This is what I have so far, but it sorts by first name"` -- That statement is incorrect. You are not sorting. You are just determining the minimum and maximum value. If you want to sort, then you will first have to use a proper [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) or simply use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Yes, my wording is incorrect. I am just looking for the min and max values.

Comment: It would have been better to edit your question to correct your mistake. All important information should always be in the question itself. Meanwhile, someone else has answered your (incorrect) question. Now, you are not allowed to correct your mistake anymore, because doing so would substantially change the question and invalidate the existing answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the `RandomNames.txt` file containing names and surnames are as follows.

```
Allan Garnier
Kingston Arnold
Hayley Jackson
Carmel Harrell
Lee Erickson
```

Below is the program that does the job you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>fullNames;

    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened. (Don't forget to write the path to your RandomNames.txt file.)
    if (std::ifstream dataStream{ "C:\\Users\\*****\\******\\RandomNames.txt" }; dataStream) {

        // Read all values in vector data
        std::vector<std::string> data(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(dataStream), {});

        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 2)
        {
            fullNames.push_back(data[i + 1] + " " + data[i]);
        }

        //Sort vector elements by last name.
        std::sort(fullNames.begin(), fullNames.end());

        //Print names sorted by last name.
        for (size_t i = 0; i < fullNames.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << fullNames[i] << "\n";
        }
        // And close the file
        dataStream.close();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The **output** of `RandomNames.txt` file sorted by last name is as follows.

```
Arnold Kingston
Erickson Lee
Garnier Allan
Harrell Carmel
Jackson Hayley
```